# Listing tags from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

The **topic** custom post type:

```
    register_post_type( $this->forum_post_type, $bbp_cpt['forum'] );

    /** TOPICS ************************************************************/

    // Topic labels
    $topic['labels'] = array(
        'name'               => __( 'Topics',                   'bbpress' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Topic',                    'bbpress' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'New Topic',                'bbpress' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Create New Topic',         'bbpress' ),
        'edit'               => __( 'Edit',                     'bbpress' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Topic',               'bbpress' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Topic',                'bbpress' ),
        'view'               => __( 'View Topic',               'bbpress' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Topic',               'bbpress' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Topics',            'bbpress' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No topics found',          'bbpress' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No topics found in Trash', 'bbpress' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Forum:',                   'bbpress' )
    );
```

The **tag** custom taxonomy:

```
function register_taxonomies() {

    // Topic tag labels
    $topic_tag['labels'] = array(
        'name'          => __( 'Topic Tags',   'bbpress' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Topic Tag',    'bbpress' ),
        'search_items'  => __( 'Search Tags',  'bbpress' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags', 'bbpress' ),
        'all_items'     => __( 'All Tags',     'bbpress' ),
        'edit_item'     => __( 'Edit Tag',     'bbpress' ),
        'update_item'   => __( 'Update Tag',   'bbpress' ),
        'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Tag',  'bbpress' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name', 'bbpress' )
    );

    // Topic tag rewrite
    $topic_tag['rewrite'] = array(
        'slug'       => $this->topic_tag_slug,
        'with_front' => false
    );

    // Topic tag filter
    $bbp_tt = apply_filters( 'bbp_register_topic_taxonomy', array(
        'labels'                => $topic_tag['labels'],
        'rewrite'               => $topic_tag['rewrite'],
        'capabilities'          => bbp_get_topic_tag_caps(),
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'show_tagcloud'         => true,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true
    ) );

    // Register the topic tag taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        $this->topic_tag_id,    // The topic tag id
        $this->topic_post_type, // The topic post type
        $bbp_tt
    );
}
```

I would like to list all (or most popular) tags of the custom post type topic.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To grab the bbpress object,:

```
$bbp = $GLOBALS['bbp'];
```

followed by:

```
$topictags = get_terms( $bbp->topic_tag_id, 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
foreach( $topictags as $topictag){
    // do stuff like printing the terms name etc
}
```